# MYSQL query using JOIN table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables one CUSTOMERS

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| FIRSTNAME | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LASTNAME  | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ADDRESS   | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and orders

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| PRODUCT_NAME  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PRODUCT_PRICE | double(10,4) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DATE_ORDER    | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ID_CUSTOMER   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| AMOUNT        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I need to "Get the first and last names of the customers who made orders in total sum greater than the average sum of all orders. Don’t care about duplicates".

Here what I've tried

```
 select FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ID, 
        AVG(PRODUCT_PRICE * AMOUNT)  
 from     CUSTOMERS C 
 join     ORDERS O 
 on       C.ID = ID_CUSTOMER 
 GROUP BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME 
 HAVING AVG(PRODUCT_PRICE * AMOUNT) < (
                 select (PRODUCT_PRICE * AMOUNT) 
                 from ORDERS 
                 where C.ID = O.ID_CUSTOMER;
```

That does not work. I need some help

Comment: Note that it's fantastically unlikely that a price would be recorded as double rather than decimal... and see normalisation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most part of your code is correct, you want just remove the part `where C.ID = O.ID_CUSTOMER;`. this is not need to calculate the average value of the order items.

using this following code you can get the required outut

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME FROM CUSTOMERS 
INNER JOIN ORDERS ON CUSTOMERS.ID=ORDERS.ID_CUSTOMER 
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.ID 
HAVING SUM(ORDERS.PRODUCT_PRICE*ORDERS.AMOUNT)>
(SELECT AVG(PRODUCT_PRICE*AMOUNT) FROM ORDERS)
```

Comment: That is it, but you have mistyped in having clause - you used ORDERS.ORDERS (twice)  ))

Comment: I have made a mistake, Thank you

Comment: @anti-k that's exact same query as mine

Comment: @K.Sathagar That's not much of a stretch. I think that much OP should be able to do himself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find average sum of all orders in a subquery.

```
select 
    C.ID,
    C.FIRSTNAME,
    C.LASTNAME,
    SUM(O.PRODUCT_PRICE * O.AMOUNT)
from     CUSTOMERS C 
join     ORDERS O 
on       C.ID = O.ID_CUSTOMER 
GROUP BY C.ID, C.FIRSTNAME, C.LASTNAME 
HAVING SUM(PRODUCT_PRICE * AMOUNT) > (
                 select AVG(PRODUCT_PRICE * AMOUNT)
                 from ORDERS)
```

Comment: That is it!! Only I do not need sum, but I refactored it simply to my needs

Comment: Glad it helped.